# Dynamically generate input field type with angular 2 and set the type of the field

Tags: html, angular

I am new to angular 2 and trying to dynamically generate a bunch of input fields based on models using angular 2. Some fields are password fields. I want to make the input fields type to password if so. I have written something like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let field of connector.type.configFields">
    <label>{{field.name}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="field.value" />
</div>
```

now problem is I want to make the field password if the field.name is password
I am thinking adding something like this to the input

```
<div *ngFor="let field of connector.type.configFields">
    <label>{{field.name}}</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="field.value" *ngIf="field.name =='Password'" type="password"  />
</div>
```

now if I do this, All my other fields which are not password simply does not get rendered. Only password field gets rendered. What am I doing wrong.(i am very new to angular2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might work but as far as I remember, setting `type` dynamically is not supported (but might be worth a try):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="field.value" [type]="field.name === 'Password' ? 'password' : 'text'"/>
```

This is the safe option:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="field.value" *ngIf="field.name === 'Password'" type="password"  />
<input [(ngModel)]="field.value" *ngIf="field.name !== 'Password'" type="text"  />
```

If `field.name` is `'Password'`, the first is added, otherwise the 2nd input is added to the DOM.

Comment: wow man the first answer worked.
thanks alot I didn't know you can do it like this. So in angular 2 we have to set the else?. Is not like other language we can just do if and not bother with else?  if I didn't specify else the result would not just be default?

Comment: `*ngIf` is about the whole element. It is added/removed to/from the DOM if the condition is truthy/falsy. `[type]="..."` is only about the attribute. I don't know of a valid expression that allows to check for one condition and returns a value and  just does nothing when the condition doesn't match. `[type]="field.name === 'Password' ? 'password' : null"` might also work.

Comment: only this answer work correctly. [type]="'number'" or type={{'number'}} not worked as expected/ the output would be not number but string/ tested by angular12

Answer (score 0):

```
 Other way around you can interpolate the type attribute of input.
 Demo :https://plnkr.co/edit/zfXqCEmaNkulRcWSs1ah?p=preview

 connector: Array<any>;
 constructor() {
 this.name = 'Angular2';
 this.connector = [
  { type: 'text', value: 'firstName' },
  { type: 'text', value: 'lastName' },
  { type: 'numeric', value: 'age' },
  { type: 'password', value: 'password' },
  { type: 'text', value: 'city' }];
 }
 inputType(type) {
 console.log(type);
 let inputType;
 switch (type) {
  case 'text':
    inputType = 'text';
    break;
  case 'numeric':
    inputType = 'number';
    break;
  case 'datetime':
    inputType = 'date';
    break;
  case 'password':
    inputType = 'password';
    break;
  default:
  }
  return inputType;
   }


<div *ngFor="let field of connector">
<label>{{field.value}}</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="field.value"  type={{inputType(field.type)}}  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add directly like this
`<div *ngFor="let form of contactForm.controls">
<input name={{form.label}} type={{form.controlType}}>

</div>`

Comment: according to type , i am taking it as string in model that will be assigned to type and it will work as if you assign string type in input