# Angular2 - cannot change input type dynamically

Tags: angular, input, angular2-forms, angular-forms, form-control

I was wondering if anyone can help explain why i am unable to change form input type dynamically?

For e.g.

```html
<user-input type="{{ isActive ? 'password' : 'text' }}"></user-input>
```

doesn't work.

But this works,

```html
<user-input type="password" *ngIf="isActive"></user-input>
<user-input type="text" *ngIf="!isActive"></user-input>
```

user-input.ts

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-input',
    templateUrl: './user-input.html'
})
export class UserInput {

    @Input()
    public isActive: boolean;

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

user-input.html

```html
<input 
    type="{{ isActive ? 'password' : 'text' }}" 
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
/>
```

```js
user-input-password.ts

import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:
      'input[type=password][formControlName],input[type=password][formControl],input[type=password][ngModel]'
})
export class PasswordValueAccessor {

    public pattern: RegExp;

    private regexMap = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;

    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) 
    public onKeyPress (e: any)
    {
        this.pattern = this.regexMap;
        const inputChar = e.key;

        if (this.pattern.test(inputChar)) {
            // success
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue i have is that when i set the type dynamically, the user-input-password directive doesn't get triggered. If i set the type to password directly then it does get trigged.

Is there another way to dynamically change input type?

Comment: I think this is a real issue. See this - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7329?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Comment: is `user-input` a custom directive? can you show it's relevant code?

Comment: It worked for <input> tag. is user-input a custom directive? Please show us what error did you get when you use `<user-input type="{{ isActive ? 'password' : 'text' }}"></user-input>`

Comment: Alternative solution is write a function to set the value and call it like 
[type]="functionName()"

Answer (score 18):

try this

```
<user-input [type]="isActive ? 'password' : 'text'"></user-input>
```

Please take a look at this

[Dynamically generate input field type with angular 2 and set the type of the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42909450/dynamically-generate-input-field-type-with-angular-2-and-set-the-type-of-the-fie)

Comment: <user-input [type]="isActive ? 'password' : 'text'"></user-input> doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

You can prefer this way. works most time:

```
<user-input #input type="password" ></user-input>
<button (click)="changeInput(input)">Change input</button>
```

ts file

```
changeInput(input: any): any {
    input.type = input.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
  }
```

Comment: I hope he want to change the type at default load.

Comment: @Anas Bin Nazeer, unfortunately i don't have a button on the page to do this. I want to be able to change the type on load.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to handle this from typescript like

```
type: string;

functiontochangetype(){
if(your condtion ){
this.type="password";
}else{
this.type="text"
}
}
```

and in HTML

```
<user-input type={{type}}></user-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looping through an object with multiple key-value pairs and displaying the "labels" and "values" dynamically (Here, I can't decide which key is going to be `"password"`). So, instead of `type` attribute, I used property binding `[type]` which eventually worked for me.

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let item of allItemsObject | keyvalue">
    <label for={{item.key}} class="col-sm-5 col-form-label">{{item.key | uppercase}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <input [type]="item?.key==='password'?'password':'text'" class="form-control" id={{item.key}} value={{item.value}} />
    </div>
</div>
```

This can help both the queries, one who wants to know how to iterate through an object to print key-values dynamically and next, on how to dynamically update the `"type" property value of <input/> tag`

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Binding input type directly to the input element did not work, but adding the condition to a parent element worked. Code is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="input.type === 'number' ">
    <input type="number">
</div>
<div *ngIf="inpyt.type === 'text' ">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```